# How accurate are neuroevolution algorithms in modelling organism evolution?

Tags: evolutionary-algorithms, neat, neuroevolution

How accurate are neuro-evolution algorithms (such as NEAT) in modelling real organism evolution?

Comment: There are a lot of types of organism. Do you have a specific subset in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modelling genetic code persistence, mutation, and meiosis for neurological features or any other biological features is not the greatest of challenges. Modelling the rest of the organism that can support neural growth and change, the electrochemistry of the many types of neurons, and the environment that favors the emergence of learned neural behaviors is challenging and still far beyond the current level of technology.